# prettier-plugin-sort-imports ignores import order

Tags: node.js, reactjs, prettier

I am using `@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports` `4.0.0` with prettier `2.6.2` and it seems that it just plainly ignores what I am writing in there. Or I cannot figure out how to correctly specify what I want. Here's what my `.prettierrc.json` looks like:

```json
{
  "printWidth": 110,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "endOfLine": "auto",
  "importOrder": ["^react$", "^./_app.scss$", "^@lc/(.*)$", "^components/(.*)$", "^[./]"],
  "importOrderSeparation": true,
  "importOrderSortSpecifiers": true
}
```

I want `react` to appear on top, then third party modules, any `.scss` or `.css` files should appear after that, and then basically anything else. But I haven't even gotten that far. So far, it even fails to put `react` at the very top and I don't know why.

I am appreciative of any help!

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I have the same issue...

Comment: @icelic I was not able to yet! I'm considering opening up some sort of bug report ticket. Though I don't see what could cause the issue. It is clearly doing _something_ different, just not what it is being told lol

Comment: For me it was something stupid, I think I put @components instead of @/components so that was the difference I think, check for that and if that does not work double check your regexes. Hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will get you far.

```
{
    "importOrder": ["^react", "^.(css|scss)$", "<THIRD_PARTY_MODULES>", "^components/(.*)$", "^[./]"],
    "importOrderSeparation": true,
    "importOrderSortSpecifiers": true
}
```

Comment: This does not get me where I need to go. I need to make sure that any direct `.css` or `.scss` imports are happening _before_ component imports.

Comment: I have updated my code to reflect this @Nachtfunke

Comment: The updated answer does what you desire @RemiSture